# DNS Lookup Time and Windows DNS Cache

Tags: http, windows-7, dns, fiddler, browser-cache

For DNS Resolution testing purposes... I want to disable all DNS caches in my Windows 7

Still I keep seeing `"DNS Lookup : 0 ms"` for consecutive requests of the same domain.

I've tried the obvious `"ipconfig /flushdns"`, and also stopping totally the service:

```
net stop dnscache
```

also this command makes the same effect:

```
 net stop "DNS Client"
```

and also I know Browser are caching DNS Lookups for very short time. So I flush their caches, close-open the browser, or I open the same domain in different browsers (Firefox, chrome, chrome incognito, IE ) to bypass that DNS Cache.

So the first time, DNS Lookup time can be 25ms (using 8.8.8.8) but then the next DNS Lookup is cached somewhere in the system and time is 0ms. And only goes away if I wait around **3 to 5 minutes** to repeat the request.

What can I do to force the system to resolve the DNS every single time, even it's 5 seconds between the same DNS request ?

Has anything to do with keep-alive or some kind of re-use of TCP connections by Windows ? It shouldn't, because I re-open the browser. But I'm out of ideas,

Could you shed some light on this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your goal is to simulate a non-existent configuration that doesn't exist in the wild (since all clients have DNS caches). It's not entirely clear why that's an interesting configuration to test, but it is possible to do so.

As you mentioned, all browsers have DNS caches. Windows' DNS client itself has a cache. Any upstream proxy you might be using also has a DNS cache.

In this case, you are hitting two problems: First, Fiddler itself maintains a DNS cache. Second, Fiddler pools keep-alive connections to the server, regardless of whether you close your browser client or not.

As described in the Fiddler book, you can control the Fiddler DNS cache using the preference `fiddler.network.timeouts.dnscache`. The default value is `150000` (measured in milliseconds, so that's 2.5 minutes). You can set this value to `0` to prevent DNS caching.

In order to prevent reuse of connections, you can either hit CTRL+X in the Fiddler session list, or call the `FiddlerApplication.oProxy.PurgeServerPipePool` method as desired.

Comment: Thanks Eric a lot for the fast answer. That explains many things. 
Why I think is interesting ?
First because I'm trying to grasp how all the DNS Cache levels work when requesting a web document. And also I'm testing Bind as DNS Cache. Also testing speed of forwarding requests to Google DNS Vs resolving it from the root servers, and finally I can see that can be useful as Web Developer when you want to test multiple times the performance of 1st-time-cold-cache  page load (that should include the time of the DNS Lookup)

Comment: btw, I found this article of yours useful to know more about Fiddler DNS Cache http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2010/05/05/peeking-at-fiddler-internals-about-cache-and-about-config.aspx

Comment: I know it's an old post but setting fiddler.network.timeouts.dnscache to 0 didn't work. Fiddler DNS lookup are still cached.

Comment: `fiddler.network.timeouts.dnscache` appears to work just fine. Can you elaborate on why you think it doesn't work? Are you sure you're not just reusing a previously used (and pooled) connection?

Comment: The OP doesn't mention Fiddler. I have the same question, and I don't use Fiddler. There are no "fiddler" entries in about:config . So what causes a delay in seeing hosts file changes on Windows 10 Home, Firefox 69.0.1?

Comment: If you're having an issue and not asking about Fiddler, please ask a new question.